# useParams() function returns undefined when getting Id from route of address url

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a route for the URL  `/:id/prices`

but `const { id } = useParams()` returns `id: undefined`

```
const Component = () => {
const { id } = useParams()
console.log(id)
```

How to get `id` from this route?

this is how routes are structured :

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Listings />} />
    <Route path="/:id/prices" element={<PricesHistory />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and by clicking on below button I should navigate to the corresponding mentioned component

```
<a href={"/" + id + "/prices"}>
  See history &rarr;
</a>
```

Comment: Please add more code details on how you are redirecting to the page and how the routes are structured.

Comment: More information added , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Link component, regular anchor tags won't work with react-router, plus they are not very good with single page application, which is react main goal:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

 <Link to={`/${id}/prices`}>Your Name</Link>
```